# How to allow users to comment in a blog post developed in Grails

Tags: forms, grails, post, comments, blogs

I have blog in a grails app, I can already display a page with a summary of all of the blog entries; and also I can display a single post when a user clicks on a "read more" button, but after doing this another gsp file shows the post content and the comments session as well. But know I want to allow users to comment trough a form, so my question is how to achieve this? I already know I need to set a params method in my form tag: < g:form name="myForm" action="save" controller="Comment" params="[id: "${k}"]" > and also I´m sending this params to save action in order to save the new comment, but how to actually save this params and how to tell the database that comment belongs to the current post
Note: the Comment domain class has "static belongsTo = [post: Post]" and the Post domain class already has the "static hasMany = [statements: Comment]"

Comment: More details: Every blog I know works in the way that if some user write a comment in a blog post, he fills out a form and clicks on send button, the page reloads again showing the new comment. So what I need is to send the params filled in the form to a controller in order to save them in the database, then render the blog pase again, which has to read all the comments stored in the database including the new one

Answer (score 1):

So your form should store the ID of the Post.

```
<g:form name="myForm" action="save" controller="comment" id="${post.id}" >
    //Form data here
</g:form>
```

Then in your controller:

```
Post post = Post.get(params.id)
post.addToComments(new Comment())
```

Comment: Are you sure I have to save the new comment in the PostController? I though I had to do this in my CommentController

Comment: You can do it in any controller you want. It would make sense to do it in the comment controller, which I have the example form going to.

Comment: That was a very concise and understandable comment that led to me further understanding your problems.